# What is the term for this derivation: "Cheeseburger comes from Hamburger" but... the word hamburger didn't refer to ham

Tags: terminology, derivation

So the title says it all really. The term hamburger doesn't refer to ham but instead the origin of the food Hamburg, but when the presence of cheese was added the new invention is referred to as a cheeseburger.

What is this type of derivation called. Where part of a word is changed due to a misunderstanding (or other reason) of a part of an original.

I recall being told this fact, but I dont remember the name for this type of derivation

Comment: There are a lot of English words derived from toponyms. They are not like other words. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_words_derived_from_toponyms

Comment: @Lambie What point are you trying to make regarding reanalysis?

Comment: Hamburger is not a food. It is a German word referring to the people who live in or originated from Hamburg in Germany. But yes hamburger is a food but ham is never part of anything. There is no ham anywhere.

Comment: the word adaption is not from "a misunderstanding". Nobody who uses the word cheeseburger thinks there is ham in a hamburger. The actual process is Hamburg --> hamburger --> burger --> cheeseburger

Answer (score 77):

This is called *rebracketing*: when the original [hamburg][er] is reinterpreted as [ham][burger]. Other examples include [alcohol][ic] > [alco][holic] and [helico][pter] > [heli][copter].

Comment: What about cases like Watergate -> <subject>gate, where the bracketing is the same but the meanings have changed?

Comment: It is also worth noting that the confusion, and the rebracketing, only happen in the languages in which a word "ham" exists, and the word "ham" actually refers to something eatable  - English being one of those languages.

Comment: @virolino Swedish has "hamburgare" and "ostburgare" ("ost" meaning cheese), but "ham" is not a Swedish word. Possibly the rebracketing came via English... but why would "ham" need to be an edible thing in order to be replaced with "cheese"?

Comment: Calques exist. In Finnish, there is [_purilainen_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/purilainen), and _hampurilainen_ originally means "Hamburger" as in "person from Hamburg".

Comment: @TurePålsson: The original  Watergate is named after the Watergate Hotel in Washington, DC. I'd argue that the rebracketing is [Watergate] -> [scandal][gate], the "cleverest" one being [Whitewater][gate].

Comment: It gets even more complex: _wiener_ /'winər/ means 'person from Vienna', and _frankfurter_ means 'p from Frankfurt'. _Wiener dog_ means dachshund, _franks'n'beans_ is a food name, and _wiener_ itself is a euphemism for penis.

Comment: @Dave: But then you need to go *one level further!* [Watergate] originates from [water][gate], because [there was going to be a ceremonial gate built on the Potomac](https://www.washingtonpost.com/wp-dyn/articles/A60120-2004Dec12.html) in the same general area (they only got around to building the stairs leading to the gate, and then decided to call the stairs a "water gate" anyway, and held concerts and such on barges on the river).

Comment: @virolino Sometimes, but "helicopter" got rebracketed despite "heli" and "copter" not being existing words.

Comment: @Draconis: you are right. The difference is that the words "ham" and "burg" not only exist, but they tend to be quite known world-wide. Unlike "helico", "pter", "heli" and "copter". Example: It is obvious to me that the bracketing is pter(o)+dactil, but it never occurred to me (until this question) that the correct bracketing would be helico+pter - i.e. recognizing the "pter". But you are right anyway.

Comment: @Draconis The fact that neither "helico" or "ptero" were particularly known words in (especially US) English probably had an impact, too. But that certainly isn't true of "alcohol". If anything, it seems that (especially US) English just likes simplifying everything and excluding the "foreignity" of words :D And shortening is a pretty common thing in languages in general (e.g. "burger" instead of "hamburger" is something that happens quite naturally).

Comment: @JacobRaihle: *but why would "ham" need to be an edible thing in order to be replaced with "cheese"* - I proposed that specificity (being edible) simply because the hamburger is something edible. Yes, we can define a "glassburger" with some definition, but we slide away from the main discussion - I guess.

Comment: @virolino I think the point was more that if Hamburg was instead called Glassburg, Americans would probably have Glassburgers (=> burgers), but still get a Cheeseburger anyway :)

Comment: @Luaan: no comment, right to the point :)

Comment: @Draconis Surely the big factor with helicopter is that the "pt" consonant combination is not part of English phonology at the beginning of words, but is allowed as two syllables coming together

Comment: Of course there are quite a few [*ptero--* = wing](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/ptero) loanwords, in which the *p* doesn't contribute to the pronunciation (as well as  some Greek-derived medical terms and the outlier *ptarmigan*).  *Helico-pter* can keep the *p* sound by virtue of the previous syllable (as @Nacht points out), and can then be shortened to *heli* (or more commonly *helo*, with /ɛ/ or /iː/ at least) as well as *copter*

Comment: When you replace part of a rebracketed word to make a new word, you have a neoloschism, yes?

Comment: Wow, lots of word-racketing going on here

Answer (score 32):

It is unclear whether *cheeseburger* was actually formed based on a misunderstanding of the etymology of the word *hamburger*. It can be noted that the word *burger* without the *ham* is also in frequent use. Instead it could be argued that *-burger* has become a [libfix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libfix):

> In linguistics, a libfix is a productive bound morpheme affix created by rebracketing and back-formation, often a generalization of a component of a blended or portmanteau word.

(Wikipedia)

Some examples mentioned in other answers and comments, such as *-copter*, *-holic* and *-gate*, can also be considered to be libfixes.

Comment: Had to look up libfix: It is very recent terminology (from 2010) but to the point.

Comment: Is the word "libfix" the answer to the original question regardless of whether "cheeseburger" was actually formed based on a misunderstanding of the etymology of the word "hamburger"?

Comment: @Chaim: good question.

Comment: Welcome, @jkej. You are quickly adding a lot of value here on LSA. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

There is some *folk etymology* involved: First, *hamburger* is given a folk etymology containing actually *ham* and then new words can be formed after the perceived model of hamburger.

The term *rebracketing* mentioned in [the answer by Draconis](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/45644/9781) is more general, it also covers cases where no folk etymology plays a role, like Sandhi shift (*a napron* -> *an apron*; *an adder* -> *a nadder*).

EDIT: And there is another term to watch: *-burger* is called a *pseudo-suffix*.

Comment: it may be worth noting that folk etymology is _also_ more general, including things like crawfish < Middle English crevis cognate with French écrevisse (and unrelated to fish or craws)

Comment: Is that like "an onion" to "a nonion"? (Thanks to Jon Richardson for that one)

Answer (score 9):

**Two relevant terms are *back-formation* and *reanalysis*** (along with [*rebracketing*](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/45644/502) and [*folk etymology*](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/45646/502)) already mentioned in other answers).

*Reanalysis* is (in my experience) the most general of these, covering all cases where a surface form originally built up in one way (morphologically, phonetically, or otherwise) is later treated as though it had been built up in a different way: e.g. *hamburg-er* to *ham-burger*, or *a napron* to *an apron*.

*Back-formation* is a bit more specific, typically applied to cases where a a new word is caused by removing affixes from a reanalysed compound; so e.g. *an apron* would not usually be described as a back-formation, *burger* from *hamburger* might be, but *pea* from *pease* (originally a mass noun, not a plural) certainly is.

Answer (score 2):

1. The expected answer seems to be **Folk Etymology** or a less biased euphemism like *Reanalysis*, as per Wikipedia

> a change in a word or phrase resulting from the replacement of an unfamiliar form by a more familiar one.

- Whether this is the correct answer should depend on context.

2. The derivatational process is **Back-formation**

> In etymology, back-formation is the process or result of creating a new word via inflection, typically by removing or substituting actual or supposed affixes from a lexical item, in a way that expands the number of lexemes associated with the corresponding root word

- Back-formation in analytic language is functionally equivalent to etymological reanalysis.

E.g. for "resurrect" to exist "resurrection" had to be reanalyzed as **verb* + *-ion*, or /ʃn̩/ as the case may be, which happened on a wider scale with similar words. Likewise, *ham* and other words in the same category likely combine with many words, so it looks like a productive pattern. That's **analogy** when entire paradigms coalesce. This is not really the case here, but it is not a closed class either.

By the time that *Cheeseburger* was coined, the *Hamburger* was likely associated with *ham* for a long time, though it would be a peculiar name when paddies are made from beef. The fact that *burger* had hitherto no meaning on its own has no bearing, because regular words like *bread, loaf* or *cran* as **cranberry-morpheme** too have no internal derivation to justify their use.

Linguistic relativity is narrower than that. The same holds in principle for *ham*. We don't have to expect an initial etymology passed on with the condiment, because Hamburg has no monopoly on meat in a bun. To expect users to conform to some lexicographic ideal is the **etymological fallacy**

Since Mett-Brötchen (cp. minced meat) are popular in northern Germany, and Hamburg's markets are popular for their fresh food, raw ham is a likely ingredient. It's possible that sailors needed conserved meat balls, but there is no obvious significance to the receipt other than perhaps clever small time marketing, which cannot be excluded. Whether in a deliberate pun or by accident, whether from *ham* ("pork"), *hum* (a big bite), archaizing *ham* ("home") ... if the word *ham* contributed to the proliferation of *hamburger* as a word, that's certainly notable from a German perspective where *ham* is otherwise less meaningful. It is *not even wrong* since the details of its origin are admittedly a bit hazy.

That would make the Hamburg origin story a folk etymology, in my humble opinion, that is, a notable account which is probably, to a certain extend, correct yet inaccurate. The older a folk etymology is, the more likely it is either still uncertain or eventually incorrect. 1. If they are correct they are simply called *etymology*, or specifically *transparent*. 2. If the origin is obscure, that's why a folk etymology emerged to stop the gap in the first place. 3. Etymology as an ongoing effort has made advances that turn recent etymologies (1) and long standing riddles (2) obsolete. A particular subset of these is the folk etymology as an object of lexicographical interest. Even if it is obviously wrong, its origin might be informative at the root.

That's why *cheeseburger* cannot be said to be based on a folk etymology: *ham* was *not replaced* with a more familiar *ham*, its meaning was rather extended one way or another, and it was not replaced with *cheese* for reasons of familiarity. It's a recent economic coinage.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Folk_etymology

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Back-formation

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cranberry_morpheme